# How can I allow users to download and automatically open files in default program

Tags: javascript, django, web-applications, adobe

I'm building a Django application and figured out how enable users to upload files (hosted by me)

Now I need to figure out how to let them click on a 'View file' button which opens the file in a default program. For example if it is a pdf, the file would open in Adobe Reader instead of in another tab. Or if it is a word doc it would open in Word (assuming that it was installed).

I know adding download links within the web app would be easy but is there a way to go a step further straight away open the file locally in an appropriate program.

Comment: This behaviour is controlled by how the user has configured their browser. You cannot override it.

Comment: This completely depends on user, websites have nothing to do with users default programs, and no web browser forces users download item to open in new tab(pdf), for example when I use chrome to downlod a pdf, it opens edge, I've set it to do so. Its a very bad security risk if allowed.